# Colour gradient across columns in table

Tags: tikz-pgf, columns

I would like to generate a white to black colour gradient across two separate columns of a table. The row in question would be entirely white on the left-hand side of column 1 and entirely black on the right-hand side of column 2.

However, the example below generates gradients for each cell of the row in question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, row 2/.style={nodes={right color=black, left color=white}}]
{
A & B \\
C & \textcolor{white}{D} \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the gradient to the row, apply it separately to the nodes as there are only two nodes. Reduce the `column sep` by `\pgflinewidth` to get rid of the narrow white line in the middle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
{
A & B \\
|[right color=black!50, left color=white]|C & |[right color=black, left color=black!50,text=white]|D \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]